Testing ATS (automatic transfer switch) for use with network rack, how to scope it safely?
I have a small home network rack and I was hoping to be able to install an ATS on it so it is easier to swap the AC source from mains power to an inverter without disrupting the equipment in a rack. I was using a consumer UPS for this but I decide to try an ATS that said it would switch in <30ms.
I tested this and when switching mains -> inverter (two different inverters) all the devices reset. I know these devices can be powered by the inverters, so I suspect either the ATS is too slow or the inverter has some soft start or something. It's only about 50W of load, so kind of surprised this happened.
What I would really like to do is put my oscope on the output of the ATS and watch what happens. But, I'm aware that probing mains AC that the scope is plugged into is dangerous.
Is there a way to do this safely without buying an active differential probe?  I am able to power the scope via a generator or a large battery bank for a while if needed. But I wanted to check here first.

Are the inverters completely unloaded before switching over? If so,they might have a bit of a hard time regulating quickly enough,so their output voltage will sag until they manage to get out of sleep and stabilise. Try loading them a bit with an old-school light bulb or something.

The one I planned on using (an AIMS 600W) has an RPi connected to one AC out, so somewhere around 5-15W all the time. In my test, the other AC out was the "generator" input to the ATS.
I also tested with a Victron Inverter/Charger I have setup with a big battery. It wasn't loaded already, but it draws about 20W from it's battery just idling. I would expect the Victron would have no trouble with sag, but it failed too.
This is why I'd like to see what is going on with a scope.

if your equipment consumes DC, it's WAY eaiser/cheaper to keep that up and running; you just need a dioide or two to make a switchover that switches in nanoseconds.

Agree with this and looking at that now as I could just remove the inverter. 3 of the 5 devices I care about now are wall wart DC powered things, so easy. The two others require opening the case to see what the AC/DC PSU inside is doing.  But, my question was really about how to safely look at AC in this situation, because I'm curious now.

One method would be to use a small power transformer to isolate and lower the voltage in order to safely measure. An ‘off the shelf’ solution would be to find a ‘wall wart’ with AC output - most are DC though which is not useful in this instance.
Due to the discontinuous waveform during the changeover period of the ATS, the inductance of the transformer may distort the waveform. It may be necessary to add a resistive load to the transformer output - an incandescent light bulb should work at a pinch. Nevertheless you should be able to get a fair idea of how fast the changeover occurs.

Thanks! I was concerned about the isolation after reading things like: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98656/using-oscilloscope-safely-with-ac-mains
I have a portable battery+inverter setup I can use to power the scope for a while, that should be safe, right?
